# How to force GWT popup.showRelativeTo() to align to the right of an element

Tags: java, gwt

I want to create a popup that displays itself aligned to the right side of my element.

By default the showRelativeTo() implementation prefers to align the popup to the left side of the passed in element. It has logic for other locales to use right alignment

How can i trigger the popup to show aligned to the right by default in a normal Locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end solution (and yes it is hacky) is to sub-class PopupPanel, and copy the whole 'position' method.

Within that method there is logic to right align, it only triggers by default if the locale expects items to be right aligned, but it is easy to add a boolean to for right alignment

Answer (score 0):

All the ways to do this are pretty hacky, but this discussion might be of some help:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3888